# Should I declare my collections in the "both" folder?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to confirm something:

If I declare my collection in the `both` folder and my `allow` and `deny` rules in the `server` folder, does it mean that, as long as it fits into `allow` and `deny` rules, the user can change the collection using the console?

Then does that mean that my publications and server methods (who are fine tuned in order to enforce confidentiality of the data) are useless, from a security point of view? (i.e. the user can still bypass them by accessing directly the collection with a console)

If I'm right, what would you advise me to do? >

- Only declare collections I can fully disclose in the `both` folder. Declare the rest in the `server` folder and only provide publications + methods.
- transfer my collection methods into allow/deny rules. How would I do then to filter the `collection.find()` queries (i.e. formerly my publications)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. As long as it matches allow/deny rules, clients can update documents via the `_id` field and the `_id` field only. Your server publications still control what documents the client has access to see (via the browser console or in code). However, if appropriate allow/deny rules are not set, the client could still potentially update a document via `_id` (if it somehow gained access to the `_id`) or insert new documents into the collection.

It sounds like you've mostly got it right already - your Meteor.methods and publications are still useful. You (hopefully) have your client *read* permissions set up via the publications, and the client *write* permissions via the Meteor.methods.

There are a couple ways forward from here:

1. If you want insert/update ability from client-side code, set your allow/deny rules accordingly. There are some advantages to doing this - client-side inserts and updates are essentially a Meteor.method that runs both on the client and server, so the client gets the advantage of seeing near-instantaneous updates, and then the server will check to confirm it's okay. If it's not, no harm no foul - the server says "that's not allowed" and the update is rolled back on the client as well.
2. Do all of your inserts and updates in Meteor.methods, and just tell Meteor to deny all updates and inserts on the collection. This means the client can't insert or update without calling a Meteor.method, and you build your security into the methods.

This post probably explains it a bit better:
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/

Comment: If I do all my inserts & update using the Meteor.methods, does that mean that I lose the latency compensation feature? i.e. simulation of db inserts/update on minimongo when offline? Concerning the `_id` availability, I use it everywhere (with restricted data access using my publications), including in the url, so I guess it is easy to the client to get his hands on it. Anyway, that's a nice answer. I'll validate it.

Comment: No, latency compensation still work as long you place `Meteor.methods` on  `both` folder.

Comment: Same idea, if I place on `both` folder the methods, since the client can call it, he can change it?

Comment: In `Meteor.methods`, you should use [`check`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check) to validate the arguments and any conditional logic (restriction) before the write (insert/update/remove) operation.  Doesn't matter you place the methods on `both` or `server` folder, same rule apply.

Answer (score 2):

1. The collection should be declared in `both` folder so that you can use it on client and server side.
2. Yes, user can write (insert/update/remove) to your collection using browser console as long as it match `allow` and `deny` rule.
3. I strongly suggest you ditch `allow` / `deny` rule approach and use `Meteor.methods` and `Meteor.call` instead where you can have greater control like validation etc. To filter data available to client, use `Meteor.publish`.